# Can I deduct a whole-blood donation as a charitable contribution on my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, charitable-contributions

I've noticed that there are several new companies advertising that they collect blood donations. I asked a friend who is an ER doctor why, and his response was that blood donations are quite valuable, and several hospital systems have started collecting blood directly because they don't want to pay so much for the blood that they use. Fair enough.

What is the fair market value of a blood donation? Should I be able to write that value off on my taxes if I am giving it to a 501(c)(3) like the Red Cross?

**Edit:** Is it the fact that the blood is being drawn on-site? Would I be able to write it off if I had the blood drawn by a third party and then I gave the whole blood donation to the Red Cross?

Answer (score 13):

> What is the fair market value of a blood donation?

[Hospitals pay $130-150 for a pint of blood](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/story?id=117431). They charge their customers more, perhaps, but it's only worth $150 to the Red Cross.

> Should I be able to write that value off on my taxes if I am giving it to a 501(c)(3) like the Red Cross?

[According to the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html), no, blood donations are considered part of the category of time and services donated to charity which cannot be deducted.

Comment: Look at it this way: if they paid you for your donation, then you'd have to pay income tax on the payment (I assume). Then you could donate the cash to them or someone else and deduct it, leaving you net flat. The general idea of tax deductions for charitable donations is to be able to give money to charity untaxed out of gross income. Your blood donation, or any other directly performed services, are already untaxed.

Comment: 100% right. But, consider, congress can easily change that line of code, codify a $150 deduction, and help a system that seems to always be running the risk of shortage.

Comment: I am allowed to write-off donations of clothing or cars, or other valuable things. Why doesn't a pint of blood have intrinsic value, why is it considered a service?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I believe one of the reasons blood centers are reluctant to pay people for their donations is the increased risk of receiving tainted blood. A tax deduction may increase this risk too, though to a lessor extent. That being said, perhaps if there are advances in technology to the point that real time blood screening tests become extremely accurate, then maybe they could just not pay you unless your blood is safe. Though that brings up other problems: "Um, sorry, we can't pay you, not sure if you knew this, but...."

Comment: A red cross that I worked at *30 years ago* was charging more than that for a pint. I bet the ARC cherry-picked the cheapest amount for that article.

Comment: Actually this is an excellent point. Giving blood to a charity should be tax-deductible.

Comment: Paying donors for blood (either by direct payment, or by tax deduction) introduces two problems: It could encourage people with unhealthy blood to donate (i.e. drug addicts), and it could encourage people to donate blood more often than is healthy for the donor.  I'm not saying that these problems are unsolvable, but that is traditionally the reason that blood donors are not paid.

Comment: @BenMiller I'm aware of the ethical concerns. I think that allowing tax deductions removes some of that problem because there is not an *immediate* benefit to the donor. (Drug addicts can't donate blood to pay for their next fix.) You could also solve the frequency problem by allowing no more than 7 donations/year. I'm a healthy donor who has not donated in a few years because it is inconvenient. I would resume donating if I could write it off like other donations.

Comment: Strictly opinion: Blood is not like other goods that can be donated like clothes, cars, or cash. You didn't pay for it, you're not taxed on owning it, you can't use it to legally generate income, and (barring medical issues) you can regenerate what you need, essentially getting it back with no loss to your "inventory". While there is a quantifiable donation with regards to the amount, really what you're donating is your time at the donation center and the service of your body being without that blood for a period of time.

Comment: There are already centers that pay for a blood donation. And in theory, that's taxable .

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I don't know of any centers in the US that will pay you for donating blood. They will pay you for donating *blood plasma* though. My understanding is that US hospitals won't use blood donated from someone that was paid.

Comment: http://firstquarterfinance.com/donate-blood-for-money/

Comment: @NathanL I presume because you had to pay money to buy the car or the clothes originally, but you didn't pay for your blood. We could debate endlessly if that's how it ought to be, but that's how tax laws actually are.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, that article is in regard to donating blood plasma.  It's my understanding that these paid-for donations are sold for research purposes and not to be used in hospital transfusions.  A friend of mine ran outreach for a rare condition blood plasma clinic.  The clinic would qualify a potential donor to note the existence of a condition and the non-existence of others, then sell the blood to research facilities studying treatments/cures for those conditions.

Comment: When trying to calculate the intrinsic value of your blood, keep in mind that quoted price needs to cover all tests and treatment the blood undergoes in order to make sure it can safely be used, proper handling and storage and logistics [physical as well as record-keeping], the check-up you receive before you are allowed to donate and so on.

Comment: @Jay Sorry to necropost, but that's a huge simplification. I would say you did pay for your blood in the sense you paid for the food your body used to make the blood, much like if you were a carpenter you would buy wood to make furniture. You buy food to make blood. Donating blood does cost you something in the increased required energy intake to regenerate it.

Comment: @Vality Interesting argument, but wow, how would you calculate the cost of the food used to produce that blood? If you didn't give blood, would you have eaten less? Maybe or maybe not. You might have just been more active to burn up the calories. What's the actual biological process to produce blood, how much food is consumed to produce 1 pint of blood, under what conditions, etc? In any case, my point is that tax law doesn't allow for a deduction. Clearly blood does have value: the hospital charges patients for blood. The doctor charges for delivering it to you. The insurance company ...

Comment: ... takes a cut. Everybody involved makes money off the deal except the blood donor, which seems very unfair to me. But I don't write tax law.

Comment: Not sure if the ARC does this, but the other blood collection agency in our area often runs promos where you are "paid" with certain gift cards usually if you donate on specific days. So you could get $10 for gas, Walmart, restaurant or movie discounts, for example. Sometimes it is even $20. Sometimes they offer pro sports team stuff or have contests for chance to win trips. Anyway, it's a far cry from $150 (unless you were to win a trip), but it is something, and I normally go only on those days since it takes so long (I donate platelets, which takes 70-90 minutes on the machine).